# Store each generated row directly in csv-file

Tags: r, performance, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I'm working with R. My problem ist that I want to generate a Dataset with 5.000.000 rows but I don't want to save each row within R in a Data.Frame because this will lead to a very bad performance.

To boost the performance I thought it would be good to save each generated Row directly to a csv-file so R doesn't has to build up an enormous Data.frame.

This is my code right now:

```
df<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:5000000){
df[i,1]<-paste(round(runif(20, min = 1, max = 1000), 0), 
        collapse = " ")
}
```

Do you have any suggestions to build up an csv-file and add each row separately without saving it to the data.frame.

Comment: Why not use `sample(1:1000, 20, replace = TRUE)` instead of `round(runif(20, min = 1, max = 1000), 0)`?

Comment: If I would need to save intermediate results for better performance I would: 1. Split data into chunks (eg 1e6 rows) and not by row; 2. Save chunks as RDS (not csv).